# How to restore permission when I am the admin of the project?

Tags: google-iam, google-cloud-iam

After mistakenly add myself to a wrong role, I am no longer able to access "IAM & admin".

While trying to extract Big Query tables to Google Storage, I received the following error,

> > bq extract --compression GZIP Dataset.TableName gs://tableName_*.csv.gz
> >     Waiting on bqjob_r4250d44ecf982a22_00000169c666b451_1 ... (23s) Current status: DONE
> >     BigQuery error in extract operation: Error processing job 'Dataset:bqjob_r4250d44ecf982a22_00000169c666b451_1': Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while writing data.

I thought I may have a permission issue, therefore I change my role in Google Cloud.  I don't remember what role I changed.  It may be owner or creator.

After that, I am not able to to access the project in Big Query, as well as "IAM & Admin" page.

> > bq extract --compression GZIP Dataset.TableName gs://tableName_*.csv.gz
> >     BigQuery error in extract operation: Access Denied: Project projectName: The user myemail@xxx.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project projectName.

Since I am the admin of this account, there is no other person who has the access.  What options do I have to restore the access?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Contact Google Cloud Support. If the folks there are able to confirm your identity, they should be able to reestablish the correct permissions to your account. As you've seen, it's a good practice to duplicate golden account likes this for this type of eventuality. Best wishes.

Comment: Since I am in Bronze support level, the only support I have is billing.  There is no tech support for me.

Comment: Let me see whether I can get someone to help you; it seems to me that you're in a irrecoverable place and need help.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, please open a case through the billing support form, and for "How can we hep?" select "other." https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

This way, I can follow up with you in private and get the details necessary to move forward. Please let me know once you submit the case and what your case number is so I can follow up.

Edit: For anyone else viewing this issue, the above method is just for this case and not the correct avenue of support for this problem. If you have a support package and you have this issue, please reach out through normal channels.

Thanks,

Hunter,
GCP Billing

Comment: Hunter, thank you.  I don't know how to make contact in private so I post it here.

This is from the subject area.
[#18905081] General Cloud Billing Query [ref:_00D00VNwG._500f21NeiW9:ref]

Thank you again!